# Single word meaning one who searches

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word in English that means something akin to "one who searches"  or "one who searches for meaning."  I am hoping for a rustic/obscure word (not a commonly used word), but not a word that's tricky to pronounce.

It could be a verb as in 'searching for meaning' in hard circumstances, for example:

> She _____ after her son's death.

or it could be a noun, as in 'one who searches for anything/everything' as in:

> If she wasn't searching for the meaning of life, then she was searching for the answer to why we look away from the poor, or why lovers break up, or even why one of her old socks always disappeared in the dryer. Yes, indeed, she was a ____.

(Okay that example is hockey, but you get my drift....)

Comment: Is there any reason 'searcher' is not appropriate?

Comment: Use "looker" unless you provide more context.

Comment: Can you please provide an example? That would help answering your question.

Comment: What options have you tried so far, which turned out to be unsuitable or inadequate?  There are many possibilities, and people here are likely simply to duplicate your efforts.  For a start, in what kind of context do you imagine using the term?

Comment: A seeker of meaning. A seeker of truth. One who searches for this type of things is a seeker.

Comment: I am hoping for a rustic word (not common), but not a word that's tricky to pronounce.  It could be a verb as in 'searching for meaning' in hard circumstances (for example, "She _____ after her son's death.")... or it could be a noun, as in 'one who searches for anything/everything' as in, "If she wasn't searching for the meaning of life, then she was searching for the answer to why we look away from the poor, or why lovers break up, or even why one of her old socks always disappeared in the dryer.  Yes, indeed, she was a ____." (Okay that example is hockey, but you get my drift....)

Comment: @Ruah "She **enquired** after her son's death.", "indeed she was a **seeker**."

Comment: @Ruah you should include such examples in your question's body itself.

Answer (score 4):

seeker

from bing:
NOUN
1.a person who is attempting to find or obtain something: 
"a tenacious seeker of the truth" ·

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

> She did some **soul-searching** after her son's death.

**soul-searching**, *noun*: A penetrating examination of one's motives, convictions, and attitudes. *adj*: Displaying the characteristics of deep or painful self-analysis

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/soul-searching

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you want [***investigator***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/investigator).

> one who observes or studies by close examination and systematic inquiry
> 'investigators who discovered new evidence that the universe was much older than had been previously estimated'

**Synonyms** experimenter, researcher
**Related Words** monitor, observer; empiric, empiricist, fact finder; field-worker; examiner, inspector

Reference:
http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/investigator

Answer (score 0):

Consider, [***quester***](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&biw=538&bih=354&tbm=bks&q=%22a+quester+after%22&oq=%22a+quester+after%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3..30i10.21558.25418.0.26098.8.8.0.0.0.0.311.609.2-1j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..6.1.310.Q4rI3Rr_zEU)

> Someone making a search or inquiry.
>
> [WordNet by Farlex](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/quester)
>
> *He quested after his lost son.*
>
> [verbs.colorado.edu](https://verbs.colorado.edu/html_groupings/quest-v.html)
>
> quest *noun*
>
> A long search for something that is difficult to find:
>   *a quest for the meaning of life*
>
> [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/quest)

Answer (score -2):

I believe "[Epistemophilia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/epistemophilia)" may be an appropriate choice.